# Tomcat has problem with HTTPS protocol launching

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have got the SSL certificates from GoDaddy and did below to add the certificate in the Keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat-6.0.45\conf\tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file D:\SSL_cert\root_cert\gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat-6.0.45\conf\tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file D:\SSL_cert\intermed_cert\gdig2.crt
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat-6.0.45\conf\tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file D:\SSL_cert\tomcat_cert\7f5fa603b3815b70.crt
```

and added below connector information in the Tomcat `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector
 port="443"
 maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150"    
 minSpareThreads="25"
 maxSpareThreads="75"
 enableLookups="false" 
 disableUploadTimeout="true"
 acceptCount="100"
 scheme="https" 
 secure="true"
 SSLEnabled="true"
 clientAuth="false"
 sslProtocol="TLS" 
 keystoreFile="D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat- 6.0.45\conf\tomcat.keystore"
 keystorePass="changeit"
 />
```

After this I restarted Tomcat and tried to browse to

```
https://localhost:8443/
```

But no success and getting `secure connection failed`. There is no error message in the catalina logs. And `localhost:8080` is working fine. The usual Tomcat homepage is loaded on `8080`. But `8443` is Not at all working.
Please check if the above followed steps are correct or not and help in this.

Comment: try `https://localhost:8080`

Comment: https ://localhost:8080/  also not working and getting Secure connection Failed

Comment: try this : https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI77m71MnVAhWMOY8KHfvkAskQFghaMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Ftomcat%2Fhow-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https%2F&usg=AFQjCNEzM4gpfrj6BRHggnuloUfKiw_D6Q

Comment: its given,$Tomcat\bin>keytool ....but keytool exists in JAVA_HOME\bin path right ? so how this will work ?

Comment: tats for `self-signed` check step 2 check server.xml

Comment: @ArunpandianM Try it why? It won't work.

Comment: You configured the `Connector` to listen on port 443, not 8443, so you should have tried `https://localhost` or `https://localhost:443`.